# Vanilla JavaScript and the DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom

I don't understand why I would use JS to alter HTML or CSS.  I understand fully why we use it to enhance the interaction of the code.

For example, why would I use "getElementByTagName("p")" to change all of my paragraphs, when I can set my paragraphs initially while I'm writing my HTML? When /in what cases would I need to address these nodes outside of JS interaction? OR, would I address the nodes only for the purpose of enhancing the interaction?

I'm just looking for a clean and clear answer.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your experience with JS will give you most clean and clear answer.

Comment: If you don't feel you need to use JavaScript, it doesn't matter what we say: don't use it. When you get to a point where you need to use JavaScript, for whatever reason, *that's* when you start to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a broad spectrum.

It's perfectly reasonable to build a static, non-javascript website, exactly as you describe.

At the other extreme are things like SPA apps, where literally the entire DOM is constructed via javascript; the raw HTML page is just an empty node into which the js framework builds and updates a DOM from source data.  One reason to do this is so that changes to the page can be made incrementally -- instead of downloading a whole new HTML file when navigating from one page to another, a SPA only needs to download the new content, and can insert it into the existing "page" replacing the old content.

In between are sites with some degree of interactivity -- most of the page is static HTML, but some sections include javascript-based interaction. Sounds like you've already got a handle on this part so I won't belabor it.

All of these have advantages and disadvantages; use whatever is appropriate for your particular site (and skillset).

(This part's a bit more opinion-based, but IMHO we're in a bit of a cambrian explosion period currently. New frameworks like React and Angular have caused people to start to rethink the "traditional" separation of content = HTML, layout = CSS, interaction = JS; and we're seeing all kinds of wacky experiments in how to distribute these responsibilities. Generate your CSS in javascript! Generate your DOM in javascript! Jumble all three together in a big wad of JSX!  Do it on the client! No, the server! No, do it isomorphically on both!  etc.  I think it's going to take a few years for this to settle out into commonly-accepted best practices.)

Comment: Thank you so very much. Your 3rd paragraph was the answer I was looking for. That explains it.  Thank yo so kindly.